# Chrome text input field keystroke lag in form with multiple selects/inputs

Tags: google-chrome, select, input, keyboard, lag

I have a sample form here:
https://jsfiddle.net/swbrains/42n5vuwz/
that has about 40 text input fields and corresponding select fields. Each select field has about 40 options in it.  I have pared down the HTML to just the text and select input fields in a table inside a form.

When using Chrome (Version 65.0.3325.181) on Windows 10 (tested on two different Win 10 PCs), typing into any of the edit fields is laggy.  It's less noticeable when simply touch typing but can be seen more easily when holding down a character to let it repeat, then holding down the Backspace key to repeat-delete each character.  Keypress/browser response is immediately on other pages/forms, but there is a noticeable delay every few characters when using this form and holding down a character to repeat.

When I use the same page on Firefox or MS Edge, the text input fields act perfectly with no lag whatsoever.  I have tried disabling Chrome's form fill-in option in case that was related somehow. I also enabled and disabled Chrome's hardware acceleration just to see if it would make a difference but it didn't.  I tried being logged in and out of my google account while using Chrome, but it didn't matter.  I've tried running the HTML through an online validator to ensure I wasn't missing a matching table row or cell tag some place, but it came back fine.

I'm stumped as to why this form causes this type of delay, and only in Chrome.

PS: The editor warned me I MUST include the code here if I reference jsfiddle, but my full form ss more than 30000 characters so then the editor warned me the body of my message was too long. To satisfy the editor, I've included ONE of the 40 select statements below, but this code alone will not duplicate the issue.  The jsfiddle has the entire form which does duplicate the issue (at least for me)  :)

```
    <form name=testform action="#" method="post">    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type=text name="textfield0" size=20 maxlength=30 value="Option 3">
            </td>
            <td>
            <select name="selector0" id="selector0" >
<option >Option 0</option>
<option >Option 1</option>
<option >Option 2</option>
<option selected>Option 3</option>
<option >Option 4</option>
<option >Option 5</option>
<option >Option 6</option>
<option >Option 7</option>
<option >Option 8</option>
<option >Option 9</option>
<option >Option 10</option>
<option >Option 11</option>
<option >Option 12</option>
<option >Option 13</option>
<option >Option 14</option>
<option >Option 15</option>
<option >Option 16</option>
<option >Option 17</option>
<option >Option 18</option>
<option >Option 19</option>
<option >Option 20</option>
<option >Option 21</option>
<option >Option 22</option>
<option >Option 23</option>
<option >Option 24</option>
<option >Option 25</option>
<option >Option 26</option>
<option >Option 27</option>
<option >Option 28</option>
<option >Option 29</option>
<option >Option 30</option>
<option >Option 31</option>
<option >Option 32</option>
<option >Option 33</option>
<option >Option 34</option>
<option >Option 35</option>
<option >Option 36</option>
<option >Option 37</option>
</select>

            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<form>
```

Thanks for any ideas anyone might have as to why this occurs in Chrome for a form such as this.